# Image position equivalent to background position

Tags: html, css, image, position

I am working on a website and I want to style an image like you style a background with background-position: center. Is there an equivalent to this for a regular image?

Thanks in advance,

Luuk

**EDIT:**

The image is responsive and contained in a container.

CSS:

```
.img-container {
max-height: 300px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.img-container img {
max-height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide what you have so far? It would help to see your HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do something like this to position the image centered.

```
.img-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-container img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I was looking for. There was also some random whitespace between my image and navbar, which is gone now. Thank you! :D

Comment: @Luuxter this does not work cross-browser, keep that in mind.

Comment: @WarreBuysse I noticed, thanks for reminding me. In this case it is no problem, luckily.

Answer (score 0):

You could go for display flex, but the support for IE is quite disastrous. If you care about browser support (which you should) go for the below example instead.

```
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/50/40" alt="">    
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/50/60" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/50/30" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/50" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Sass:

```
.list {
  text-align: center;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  background: red;

  img {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%; 
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
}
```

Make sure to add the prefixes for the transform attribute as well.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k433b6up/

Answer (score 0):

Your desired result isn't exactly clear, but here are some options for two different interpretations:

Changing the display property of the image and setting the text alignment to its container will maintain it's native height and width while centering it in the container:

```
.img-container {
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

.img-container img {
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5suo8tbw/

If you're trying to achieve a background fill with an `img` element you should consider using the `object-fit: cover` attribute. This will always fill your container's dimensions, maintain the image's aspect ratio, and center it in the container.

```
.img-container {
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.img-container img {
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5suo8tbw/1/

Here's a link to the spec: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

For cross browser support, check out the polyfill: https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit

Answer (score 0):

`object-fit` and `object-position` properties of an `img` are equivalent to `background-size` and `background-position` properties of a block element with `background-image`, respectively. In the following snippet, please note that the container size is `300px * 300px` while the image size is `500px * 300px`.

```css
.imageContainer {
   margin: 15px;
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   border: 5px solid lightgreen;
 }

.image {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   object-fit: cover;
   object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='imageContainer'>
  <img class='image'src='https://picsum.photos/500/300' alt='lorem picsum' />
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the object-position and object-fit, it's basically the same as background-position:

```
object-position: center
```